# Java: Create a new dir with 777 permissions on Mac

Tags: java, php, permissions

I am trying to create a directory with 777 permissions on Mac.

I am using this but I cannot delete the directory with php:

```
File f = new File("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/images/directoryName");
f.setWritable(true);
f.mkdir();
```

When I try to delete this directory I am getting this:

```
unlink(project/images/directoryName/subFile): Permission denied in
```

I need to create  folders and files on htdocs folder with my Java App and delete or edit them using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/images/directoryName");
```