# How to set permissions of certain folders to 777 on Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, mamp, 777

I need to set the permissions of just 3 specific folders (on my Mac) to 777
I went to CMND+i (get info) but the folder permissions seemed to be Read and Write - but this didn't seem to fix it.

I am trying to work out how to do this, because I am using MAMP on my Mac to try and run a localhost server to test a website. Reason; I am trying to run the script of a PHP website. It is asking me to change the permissions of certain folders in order to proceed with the 'install'.

I think the closest match to a possible answer is here:
[Java: Create a new dir with 777 permissions on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575919/java-create-a-new-dir-with-777-permissions-on-mac)

But, this appears to be Java. I assume that I need to be able to do this via either MAMP or Terminal. If anyone could please advise me which program/tool to use and what to type in, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it in a terminal, to create "/some/directory/some/where" you can use -

```
# EDIT: 777 not 077.
mkdir -p /some/directory/some/where && chmod 777 /some/directory/some/where
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to enter this into Terminal: mkdir -p localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2 && chmod 077 localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2 ...but when I refreshed the Etano intall page, it still complained that the same folders needed to have their permissions changed. I also tried this: mkdir -p /newuser/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2 && chmod 077 /newuser/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2 ...also to no avail.

Comment: @Toby Edited. It should have been chmod 777 for 777 permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to paste this directly into Terminal: `mkdir -p /localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2 && chmod 777 /localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/etano/cache2` ...and it didn't say "No such file or directory" which is an improvement. But, it still hasn't made any changes to my Etano install page... so I guess I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I use it this way: chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).